# html2canvas not work in ie9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas

I want to convert div to canvas and in chrome it works good but in IE9 it convert it but not good- its cut the div content and change the order of div elements.

witch js should i download that work well in IE9 too? 
Someone have any idea how can I resolve this resolution problem?
my js code:

```
 $scope.canvastoimage = function () {
        html2canvas($("#mytryapp"), {
           proxy: "server.js",
            useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);  
                 $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                $("#mytryapp").hide();
                printthispage();

       }
        });
    }
```

The result is attached:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code works well in all browsers

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById(mytryapp)], { 
 onrendered: function (canvas) { 
   var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
   document.getElementById('img-out')[0].innerHTML = imageData;
 } 
});
```

Test it and see how it goes. The index 0 is used with jQuery objects to get "real" document element so if you are not using jquery change to this:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById(mytryapp)], { 
     onrendered: function (canvas) { 
       var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
       document.getElementById('img-out').innerHTML = imageData;
     } 
    });
```

Comment: I need to append the converted canvas to my  $("#img-out") how can I do that? can you add some code? Thanks

Comment: I edited just now document.getElementById(#mytryapp) was wrong so i add document.getElementById(mytryapp) without #

Comment: my img-out:
<div id=​"img-out" class=​"printimage ng-scope">​</div>​

Comment: it dont have[0]